# People who ONLY go to a certain place. How would you create a query for this?

Tags: mysql, sql

Given the table frequent(drinkers,bar) that shows which drinkers regularly go to a certain bar. How would you find the drinkers who frequent ONLY, let's say, "Tavern"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Beginner Query Logic With 3 Tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32554141/sql-beginner-query-logic-with-3-tables)

Comment: Looks like whole class will deliver same answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what this has to do with 3 tables but:

```
SELECT * FROM FREQUENT
WHERE BAR = 'TAVERN' 
    AND DRINKER NOT IN (SELECT DRINKER FROM FREQUENT WHERE BAR <> 'TAVERN')
```

First get a list of people who go to tavern then exclude any who go to any bar that's not tavern.